# Running linux commands inside bash script throws permission denied error

Tags: linux, bash

We have linux script in our environment which does ssh to remote machine with a common user and copies a script from base machine to remote machine through `scp`.

Script Test_RunFromBaseVM.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

machines = $1
for machine in $machines
do
    ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${machine} "mkdir -p -m 700 ~/test" 
    scp -r bin conf.d ${machine}:~/test
    ssh -tt ${machine} "cd ~/test; sudo bash bin/RunFromRemotevm.sh"
done
```

Script RunFromRemotevm.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")"
```

Before running Test_RunFromBaseVM.sh script base vm we run below two commands.

`eval $(ssh-agent)`
`ssh-add`

Executing `./Test_RunFromBaseVM.sh "<list_of_machine_hosts>"` getting permission denied error.

`[remote-vm-1] bin/RunFromRemotevm.sh:line 2: /bin/date: Permission denied`

any clue or insights on this error will be of great help.
Thanks.

Comment: Does your script have the execute bit set?  Also, where are you declaring machine?  Is that an environment variable?

Comment: @StephenNewell just updated the question. I had abstracted out the code earlier. As far my understanding running script prefixing `bash` need not have execute bit set. May be I am wrong. 
I have executable permission set on script file.

Comment: You need the script to be executable the way you're running it.  If you want to keep it non-executable, try bash path/to/your/script.

Comment: base script I am running like this `./Test_RunFromBaseVM.sh` which has execute permission but the script that is called inside this base script is run like this `bash path_to_script` which is causing the permission denied error.

Comment: Two things stand out: sudo performs a permission check, so that could be causing the problem (try replacing the line with something else for testing maybe). Also, your error mentions /bin/dirname but that doesn't show up in your script.

Comment: Uff sorry again thats the wrong error out of cpp. 
Tried these things..
1. replaced `ssh -tt ${machine} "cd ~/test; sudo bash bin/RunFromRemotevm.sh` to `ssh -tt ${machine} "cd ~/test; echo "$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")"`
 Output: It ran fine outputting date.  
2. Ran this `ssh -tt ${machine} "cd ~/test; bash bin/RunFromRemotevm.sh` got same error

Comment: Your scp command sends the files to `~/ffdc`.  When you try to execute it, you are going into `~/test`, then execute `bin/RunFromRemotevm.sh`.  So your script should be in `~/test/bin/`.  In order to be allowed to run any command through SSH, your user should be able to do it "manually".  So ssh to the machine and run the commands manually.  It will help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @SureshSubbaiah: `ssh -tt ${machine} "cd ~/test; echo "$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")"` runs `date` on YOUR machine, and puts the result inside the SSH command line.  It's not a valid test of whether `date` runs correctly at the other end.

Comment: As a very tangential aside, `echo "$(command)"` is much better written simply `command`.  Capturing the command's standard output only so you can print it to standard output simply wastes a process for nothing.

Comment: Remove the spaces around `=` in `machines=$1`

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Format your edits. Comments make it hard to read.

Comment: By the way, I'm sure it's just a copy/paste typo, but you forgot the closing double quote on the line: `ssh -tt ${machine} "cd ~/test; sudo bash bin/RunFromRemotevm.sh`. It should of course be `ssh -tt ${machine} "cd ~/test; sudo bash bin/RunFromRemotevm.sh"`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is the presence of the `NOEXEC:` tag in the sudoers file, corresponding to the user (or group) that's executing the `"cd ~/test; sudo bash bin/RunFromRemotevm.sh"` command. This causes any further execv(), execve() and fexecve() calls to be refused, in this case it's `/bin/date`.

The solution is obviously remove the NOEXEC: from the main `/etc/sudoers` file or some file under `/etc/sudoers.d`, whereever is this defined.

Comment: Thanks it gave me pointers to look at the sudoers file under `/etc/sudoers.d`  
`Cmnd_Alias     FFDCUSER_SUDOCMDS = /usr/bin/su - root,/usr/bin/ls,/usr/bin/cd,/bin/cat,/usr/bin/ps,/sbin/service,/usr/bin/monit,/usr/bin/cp,/bin/bash,/bin/dirname,/bin/basename,/bin/date,/bin/mkdir,/bin/grep,/bin/awk,/bin/rm,/bin/hostname,/bin/sed,/bin/chown
User_Alias     FFDCUSER_SUDOUSER = ffdcuser
FFDCUSER_SUDOUSER ALL= NOEXEC: NOPASSWD: FFDCUSER_SUDOCMDS`

We have /bin/date in sudoers file, NOEXEC is added for security purpose.I believe having /bin/date in sudoers should allow cmd to execute.

Comment: Yes, having /bin/date in sudoers would allow you to do `sudo date`, but what you're doing is `sudo bash` and that bash is executing another subprocess `/bin/date` and that's the bit that's denied. You can execute /bin/date directly from sudo, but not via sudoed bash. Not as a subprocess.